# Ignore base class View public functions in Subclass documentation with Dokka

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

I generated documentation with Dokka for a View subclass. Works well, but the docs include the hundreds of public functions of the base View class. Is there a way to only document my subclass public functions?

I tried adding these options to the Gradle task but I don't think this is what it was meant for:

```
dokkaHtml {
    dokkaSourceSets {

        create("main") {
            noAndroidSdkLink = true
            perPackageOption {
                skipEmptyPackages = true

                includeNonPublic = false

                prefix = " android.view.View"

                suppress = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no option to that, we plan to add dedicated flag to turn it on/off.

You can follow this issue to get current state on that case: https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/1501

Comment: It's ridiculous that Dokka does this by default, it defeats the whole purpose of sharing project-specific documentation if our docs are flooded with this Android SDK noise.